# Storybook 7 with nextjs keeps crashing with error 'EBUSY: resource busy or locked'

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js, storybook

Storybook works for a short bit but as soon as anything compiles in error it crashes. Sometimes it crashes for no reason. Sometimes it won't even start for no reason and I just need to try again.

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/addon-styling": "^1.3.7",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/nextjs": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/react": "^7.4.5",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^20.7.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.5.3",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.30",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "storybook": "^7.4.5",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.3",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2"
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

This is an old problem but the old solution is no longer works with Storybook 7 - https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/19336

ManagerWebpack is no longer configurable https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/builders/webpack

Comment: Please add the exact error to the question. Also, the solution you tried and didn't work.